# Could not find class 'org.tukaani.xz.LZMAInputStream'

Tags: android, extract, 7zip

I used library `apache` commons compress 1.9 and x.z-1.4 for extracting 7zip file. I used it in the 2 processes. 
First, I downloaded 7zip file via WIFI and then when the download has been done, i extracted it, it was successfully. 
Second, I downloaded 7zip file via FTP and then when the download has been done, i extracted it, it was failed. When i debugged it, error appear with a reason "Could not find class `org.tukaani.xz.LZMAInputStream`.

I really confused, why it suddenly did not found, because when i tried in the first process, the error did not appeared

Anybody, can help me Please.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the class `org.tukaani.xz.LZMAInputStream` is not included in you project.

As it has shown on [mvnrepository of xz](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tukaani/xz/1.5),
you can simply add it to your `build.gradle` under `dependencies`.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tukaani/xz
compile group: 'org.tukaani', name: 'xz', version: '1.5'
```

By the way, if you want a simple library for compress and decompress, I would recommend you to try out [jarchivelib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.rauschig/jarchivelib/0.7.1).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  xz-1.4.jar

I found the answer [here](http://www.progtown.com/topic1904529-it-is-impossible-to-archive-a-file-7z.html) -

This is the dependency if u use maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tukaani</groupId>
        <artifactId>xz</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```